# file content in a table form needed to be converted in a dictionary in python

Tags: python

abc.txt file content are as -

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
|                  ID                  |   Status  | Display Name | Size | Volume Type | Bootable | Attached to |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| 43c51829-20f8-422d-a667-ce2ed917a33c |  creating |   New-Vol    |  2   |     None    |  false   |             |
| 7b388ad1-eec9-44fc-b9b1-240c0681d106 | available |   New-Vol    |  2   |     None    |  false   |             |
| d4649bda-eb4f-40f9-a856-254f51f274ae | available |   New-Vol    |  2   |     None    |  false   |             |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

How to covert this content in to a valid dictionary using python ??

tried code -

```
def _table2dict():
#    f = open('abc.txt', 'wt')
#    f.write(body)
#    f.close()
    table = [line.strip().split('|') for line in open("abc.txt", 'r')]
    del table[0]
    del table[1]
    del table[-1]

    result = {'volumes' : []}
    for a_row in table[1:]:
        tmp = {}
        for key, value in zip(table[0][1:], a_row[1:]):
            key = key.strip(' ')
            value = value.strip(' ')
            tmp[key] = value
        result["volumes"].append(tmp)
    return result

x = _table2dict()
print x
```

I tried above command it gives some sort of output.

Comment: Is there anything that you already tried to solve this problem? If you have not put in any effort yourself and you just ask the community to give you the code, then this is not really in the spirit of this site. If you have tried various things which don't work the way you expect, post them with e.g. an error message or why the behavior differs from what you expect, I am sure people will be glad to help. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just for clarity, those `+`, `-` and `|` characters aren't actually part of your file, are they? If they aren't, how are columns delimited?

Comment: they are part of file

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (probably not the most pretty python code imaginable):

```
def _table2dict():
    entries = {'volumes' : []}
    fields = ()
    for line in open("abc.txt",'r'):
        entry = {}
        if not line.strip().startswith("+-"): # get rid of +--- lines                                                                                                                                                             
            cells = [x.strip() for x in line.split("|")[1:-1] ] # weed out first and last | and get rid of whitespace                                                                                                                        
            if len(fields) == 0: # first get field names if we don't have it already
                fields = [cell for cell in cells]
                # do not process this line and skip to next in file
                continue

            if len( fields) != 0: # we already found the field names                                                                                                                                                              
                for (key,value) in zip(fields, cells):
                    entry[key] = value
                entries["volumes"].append(entry)

    return entries

x = _table2dict()
print x
```

Output (formatting for readability):

```
{'volumes': 
    [
      {'Status': 'creating', 'Bootable': 'false', 'Attached to': '', 'Display Name': 'New-Vol', 'Volume Type': 'None', 'ID': '43c51829-20f8-422d-a667-ce2ed917a33c', 'Size': '2'}, 
      {'Status': 'available', 'Bootable': 'false', 'Attached to': '', 'Display Name': 'New-Vol', 'Volume Type': 'None', 'ID': '7b388ad1-eec9-44fc-b9b1-240c0681d106', 'Size': '2'}, 
      {'Status': 'available', 'Bootable': 'false', 'Attached to': '', 'Display Name': 'New-Vol', 'Volume Type': 'None', 'ID': 'd4649bda-eb4f-40f9-a856-254f51f274ae', 'Size': '2'}
    ]
}
```

Note that I created a dict for every entry in addition to having the final output being a dict. The order of the fields is thus not the one you have in the original file but every field can be retrieved by the name given in the header.

Does this do what you had in mind?

edit: in first version I had an extra empty field in the output because of the last '|' character that I didn't take care of, now fixed

Comment: @user2069033 just curious whether this is doing what you had in mind or if there is anything that is still missing?